# Migrate VS2017 Azure DevOps pipeline to VS2019

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

We have a VS solution that currently uses the **Hosted VS2017** agent on **Azure DevOps**. We now want to upgrade our solution to *VS2019*. However, I can't see any way to amend / update the **Azure DevOps** pipeline to use the **windows-2019** agent. It only seems to be available when creating a new **Azure DevOps** pipeline.

Is there a way to amend / update our current **Azure DevOps** VS2017 pipeline to the 2019 hosted agent without having to re-create our pipeline from scratch?

**UPDATE**

As can be seen from the screenshots below VS2019 doesn't appear in the dropdown list of available agent pools.

[image]

Comment: Do you use yaml pipelines or the UI pipelines?

Comment: I used the UI pipelines

Answer (score 5, accepted):

windows-2019 agent is not listed in Agent pool field. As agents are managed in agent pools, you can choose agent pool `Azure Pipelines`.

And then you will need to choose an agent in the **agent specification** field. You will find agent windows-2019 there.

[image]